# How do I get the pointer to the first item in a vector for qsort's first argument?

Tags: c++, pointers

I know that to get the pointer to the first element of a vector, you can do:

```
&myvector[0];
//or
&myvector.front();
```

I want to use the pointer above to insert it as the first argument for [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). The problem is, when I do this:

```
qsort(graph->&edge[0], ..., ..., myComparatorFunction);
```

I get this error `expected unqualified-id before '&' token`. The `graph` refers to an instance of a self-made class below:

```
class Graph {
public:
    int V, E;
    vector<Edge> edge;
};
```

The instance is created using:

```
Graph* createGraph(vector<Edge> edge) {
    Graph* graph = new Graph;
    graph->edge = edge;
    return graph;
}
```

How do I get rid of the error while achieving what I want?

Comment: Don't use `qsort`.  Use `std::sort` instead.

Comment: @NathanOliver Why?

Comment: `&x` is the adress of `x`. You want to get the adress of `graph->edge[0]` ... the rest I'll leave to you. In the past I became increasingly unsure about votes as typo, though I'll just vote and see who agrees or not

Comment: @Richard because it is type safe and possibly more efficient

Comment: First, `qsort` does not use the type system like `std::sort` does.  Second, `std::sort` can be used with functors, lambdas and functions unlike `qsort`.  Third, `qsort` has worst case `O(N^2)` comparisons while `std::sort` is `O(NlogN)`.

Comment: Also `qsort` is not guaranteed to work if you're sorting a non-POD type.  See the [info here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort), and read what happens if the type being sorted is not a `TrivialType`.

Comment: @Richard `qsort` vs `std::sort` is _the_ classical example of templated code being faster than code using function pointers. https://martin-ueding.de/articles/qsort-vs-std-sort/index.html

Comment: `std::sort(graph->edge.begin(), graph->edge.end(), myComparatorFunction);`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof _"The main point is that the C++ version is way faster than the C version"_ Funny, that's not what his graphs look like to me. Perhaps he doesn't realise that 10^0 is 1?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit He is talking about the right half of the graph (beyond 10^4, where it's almost one full tick above 1 x 10^0, i.e. at 2 x 10^0). And he correctly observes that the profiling at low element counts is noise (look at the other graph and the code... He attempts to measure individual 10^-6 intervals, with a whopping 5 repetitions).

Comment: @Max Not sure I'd call 10^0.2 (1.584) _"way faster"_ but okay maybe that's just me.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Respectfully, that's not how log-scale plots work. The tick at 10^0 is 1x10^0, the next tick (not the green whisker from the green x=10^1 data point's error bar!) is 2x10^0, the next one is 3x10^0 etc. That's why the tick density increases as you approach the next decade: 8x10^0 and 9x10^0 are of course closer together on a log-scale axis than 1x10^0 and 2x10^0. The data points are just below 2x10^0, 1.9 is the correct reading. And "twice as fast" is "way faster" for me at least - that's not peanuts for such a fundamental algorithm.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

Compose the expressions like so:

- The vector is `graph->edge`.
- Its first element is `graph->edge[0]`.
- The address of that is `&graph->edge[0]`.

(This could also be spelt `graph->edge.data()`, using vector's own interface more directly.)

Your `graph->&edge[0]` is just not meaningful.

---

Also I recommend `std::sort` over `qsort` unless you *know* you need the latter for some reason. It's type-safe and it can take more "things" (e.g. capturing lambdas, and other inlineable functors).

And, it will try to be the best sort it can be. The same is true of `qsort` (despite the name, which suggests it'd always use quicksort), but `std::sort`'s worst-case algorithmic complexity is required to be better than `qsort`'s is permitted to be.

Comment: probably should be `graph->data()` instead, or even better not to use `qsort` in C++

Comment: @Slava Good point re `data()` (though it is presumably `graph->edge.data()`)

Comment: Plus `std::sort` may inline function calls (unlike `qsort()`) which can be significant in some cases.

Comment: @Slava I've stolen this too :)

Comment: No problem, my comments are not to criticize but make your answer better

Comment: @Slava And that they do!

Comment: To me "it's worst-case algorithmic complexity, though, is required to be better than what `qsort`'s is permitted to be" is unclear in what you are trying to imply. Is that a disadvantage (does the average/best case suffer) or is it a benefit?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I'm just saying `std::sort`'s worst performance is better than `qsort`'s worst performance, in terms of guarantees. Per Nathan: _"`qsort` has worst case `O(N^2)` comparisons while `std::sort` is `O(NlogN)`."_

Comment: Ok, the "though" makes it confusing. Also, I don't get the "despite the name", but that might just be me.

Comment: @MaxLanghof "qsort" illicits thoughts of "quicksort", but it may not be implemented as such.

Comment: @MaxLanghof I rephrased it a bit